# pandas for index, row in dataframe.iterrows()

Tags: pandas

I was not able to figure out the reason why my code didn't work. Ii seemingly doesn't have any problem for me. Can anyone help to point out the issue in my code?

**What I tried:**

```
true_avengers['Deaths'] = 0
for index, row in true_avengers.iterrows():
    for i in range(1,6):
        col = 'Death{}'.format(i)
        if row[col] == 'YES':
            row['Deaths'] += 1
```

[image: result of what I tried]

**Answer:**

```
def clean_deaths(row):
    num_deaths = 0
    columns = ['Death1', 'Death2', 'Death3', 'Death4', 'Death5']

    for c in columns:
        death = row[c]
        if pd.isnull(death) or death == 'NO':
            continue
        elif death == 'YES':
            num_deaths += 1
    return num_deaths

true_avengers['Deaths'] = true_avengers.apply(clean_deaths, axis=1)
```

[image: result of answer]

Much appreciated if you can enlighten me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not use pandas correctly. It is *usually* not necessary to loop through the rows explicitly. Here's a clean vectorized solution. First, identify the columns of interest. Their names consist pf "Death" followed by a number:

```
death_columns = true_avengers.columns.str.match(r"Death\d+")
```

Find out which of them are "YES":

```
changes = true_avengers.iloc[:, death_columns]=='YES'
```

Calculate the sum of the occurrences and add them to the last column:

```
true_avengers['Deaths'] += changes.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much DYZ!